# should the repository be able to work with entities or just return data?

Tags: clean-architecture

Should a repository function return a entity from the database?

For example if I had a entity like this:

```
class Person(
    int id,
    string name,
    int age
) { ...
```

and a repository metod, that returns a Person entity like this:

```
public Person findPersonById(int id)
```

should this method return the Person entity, so that the repository creates the entity and just returns it, or should the repository return a model with just the data of the PersonEntity and not the entity per se like this:

```
data class PersonModel(
    int id,
    string name,
    int age
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A repository object (PersonRepository) is aimed to return a domain entity (Person), by design.

That same repository object probably makes a call to some external resource (person api for example), which returns a model (PersonModel/PersonDTO) to be transformed into domain entity already mentioned. Also, by design.

Later on, presentation layer (or api layer) should probably transform domain entity into a view-model (PersonViewModel) to be returned to client. Again, by design.

Of course, in case your api has few if any business rules, you may want to skip DTOs (PersonModel, PersonViewModel) and work with a(n anemic) domain entity through all layers (infrastructure, application, presentation).

In sum, the repository object "bakes" an entity for the domain (application) layer.